# Box.net API Is there a way to extend expiring time of access tokens?

Tags: box-api

Is there a way to extend expiring time of access tokens for Box API?

"Each access_token is valid for 1 hour" is too short to my application and "Refresh token" is not much use.

I do really need a long expiring time. Any help appreciated.

Comment: There is currently no way to get an access token that lives longer than 1 hour.  Can you say more about why the refresh token is not of much use?

Answer (score 0):

The access token is valid for one hour, but the refresh token can be used to retrieve a new access token that is valid for an additional hour. There currently is not a way to extend the life span of an individual access token.